# how to create progress bar from ajax loop?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

**My server side data is following:**

```
$total=100;
$jd=array();
for($i=1;$i<=$total; $i++){
    $jd["current_value"]=$i;
    $jd["total"]=$total;
    $jd["some_extra_data"]="Extra data-$i";
    echo json_encode($jd);
    sleep(1);
}
```

Now i want to create a progress bar from above ajax request data.

But i don't get a single data from request. all time i get full data. so, i cant create a progress bar. 
how can i apply request?
Please me. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not too adverse to using a JS library then you might consider using JQuerys UI library for this.

http://jqueryui.com/progressbar/

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Progressbar - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
      value: 50
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="progressbar"></div> 
</body>
</html>
```

If you were to combine this with the JQuery Ajax request then you should be able to achieve what you are after: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

You can then periodically call the server side page to get a value to populate the progress bar.

Let me know if thats in the direct direction and I can elaborate if need be.